# How can I play a seamless audio loop from the command line?

Tags: macos, audio

I have tried `afplay` but it doesn't have the option to loop (repeat the audio) and if I try to repeatedly call it in a loop there is a gap of dead space at the end of each loop.

I'm trying to play white noise continuously, so any crack, pop, or dead time between loops is completely unacceptable.